# Strange C++ Type Casting

Tags: c++

While following an [openGL tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/), I came across this piece of code:

```cpp
unsigned char header[54];

// [...]

unsigned int dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
```

I don't understand the use of `*(int*)&`. Why not simply use `(int)` ?

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, `*(int*)&(header[0x0A])` looks like a strict aliasing violation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not simply use (int) ?'

Because `(int)header[0x0A]` would convert only a single byte at address 0x0A when the intention is to reinterpret a sequence of `sizeof(int)` bytes instead.

That said, the example has undefined behaviour because it violates "strict aliasing" rules. Also, I don't know why they cast to `int*` and then convert to `unsigned int`. A well defined alternative:

```
std::memcpy(&dataPos, header + 0xA, sizeof dataPos);
```

Comment: Is there any concise way to respect "strict aliasing" in this case ?

Comment: @Garfield1002 I think `std::memcpy(&dataPos, &header[0xA], sizeof dataPos)` should do the trick.

Comment: I'd like to remind that this kind of pointer arithmetic is not safe. In this case it would work, but if some kind of fancy new compiler defines a char as 2 or more bytes, then it would silently create runtime problems. `std::memcpy(&dataPos, &header[0xA], sizeof dataPos);` would be much safer and MISRA compatible.

Edit: @mediocrevegetable1 seen your comment after sending mine. I'm keeping it since it explains why it is necessary.

Comment: @MuratUrsavaş `&header[0xA]` and `header + 0xA` are exactly equivalent and neither is safer than the other as far as I can tell. char is by definition always exactly 1 byte and never more. If you mean that there could be a problem when a byte is different size than 8 bits, then `&header[0xA]` will have that same problem. If MISRA requires former style and if you need to conform to MISRA, then by all means use that style, but that's all it is: a matter of style.

Comment: @eerorika I know, char definition is exactly one byte and a new compiler with a different char size is quite a low probability. Take this as a rule of thumb suggestion for all types. Pointer arithmetic generally leads to bugs which could be easily avoided. We all do that and it's better to stay away from it. MISRA rule had been created due to this reason, not for just some kind of coding style.

Answer (score 3):

Since `header` is a `char` array, the cast here is taking the **address** of header at the position `0x0A` making it into a `int*` pointer and reading from that address as if it was an `int`. It is effectively reading 4 bytes (or the size of int on your system) of the header starting from the position **0x0A** and packaging them into a single int.

The simple `(int)` cast would only convert the value at the position `0x0A` from `char` to `int`, but would not get the values on the other 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`*(int*)&(header[0x0A]);` means first `&header[0x0A]` is casted into `int*` to match `header`'s type to return then `*` is used to de-reference the whole variable so that variable resulting isn't a pointer anymore